# pygame music rewind is delayed

Tags: python, pygame

I am using pygame to 'seek' to a position in an mp3 file using a playback slider. Moving forward in the file is fine. However, when I try to go backwards there is a delay of several seconds before the 'jump' happens.

This is the same whether I use `pygame.mixer.music.set_pos()` or `pygame.mixer.music.play()` with an offset.

It seems like there's an internal pcm buffer that should be flushed. Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: What version of pygame are we talking about?

Answer (score 0):

From the [pygame docs:](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/music.html#pygame.mixer.music.set_pos)

> `pygame.mixer.music.set_pos()`
>
> This sets the position in the music file where playback will start. ... For MP3 files, it is the relative position, in seconds, from the current position. For absolute positioning in an MP3 file, first call `rewind()`. ...

`rewind()` will reset the playback of the current song to the very beginning, so it appears that moving forward is supported, but moving back isn't. So to move back, you must go the beginning and then jump forward.

Comment: `rewind()` has the same bug described above: it continues playback from the old location for a few seconds, then jumps to the beginning.

Comment: @cmbryan Strange. I'll look into it more. Could you post some of your code?